# can't login to FTP after upgrading to 13.04

Tags: upgrade, 13.04, ftp, vsftpd

I'm using vsftpd as ftp server. Till upgrading 13.04 ftp worked normally, i used my user/password as ftp password. But after upgrading to 13.04 i can't login to ftp. I added new user to system, can't login to ftp with new username too.

I removed the vsftpd, and installed again, same problem.

How i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem too, then i used Pure-FTPd instead,the Pure-FTPd still work.